# How to create, modify, and return array of pointers in a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

Here's a very basic example of what I'm trying to do (note that this segmentation faults)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo {
    int *bar;
} Foo;

Foo **fooPointers() {
    Foo **test = (Foo**) malloc(sizeof(struct foo) * 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Foo *curr = *(test + i);
        int *num = &i;
        curr->bar = num;
    }
    return test;
}

int main() {
    fooPointers();
    return 0;
}
```

the goal is to create an array of pointers of `Foo`, give each element meaningful values, and then return the pointer array.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to why this doesn't work and how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: malloc the wrong size for a start. If you want to malloc space for 3 pointers, you used the wrong size. Or if you want to malloc space for 3 struct foos, you used the wrong type for the result.

Comment: assuming the goal is in fact "create an array of pointers to Foo" then you need to set each pointer to point somewhere. Currently you copy and dereference uninitialized pointers.

Comment: yeah i think i got a bit confused between arrays of pointers vs arrays of structs

Comment: Making your array of pointers (the `bar` elements) point to a local variable in the function is not going to work well once the function returns.  You'd be better off setting those pointers to NULL.

Comment: is there no way to give them values within the method body? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You can give them values in the function, but the objects pointed at must survive beyond the lifetime of the function.  Global variables or allocated memory, or perhaps pointers passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo
{
    int *bar;
} Foo;

Foo **fooPointers()
{
    Foo **test = malloc(sizeof(Foo*) * 3);  // should be `sizeof(Foo*)`
    
    static int k[] = {0,1,2};  // new array

    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        test[j] = malloc(3*sizeof(Foo));  // No need to cast output of malloc
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Foo *curr = *(test + i);
        //int *num = &i;
        curr->bar = &k[i]; // storing different addresses.
    }
    return test;
}

int main()
{
    Foo **kk;

    kk = fooPointers();

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(kk[i]->bar));  //printng the values.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: is `sizeof(Foo*)` equivalent to 1?

Comment: also, i recall someone commented and said im just copying and dereferencing pointers, so does your code modify the pointer array being returned?

Comment: `sizeof(Foo*)` is 8, since it is a pointer (Mine 64 bit system).  Note : structure contains only one integer pointer.

Comment: i just ran the code @ https://repl.it/languages/c, isn't it supposed to print 0, 1, 2?

Comment: No. We are assigning the address of `i` in the `fooPointers` . By the time the function returns, the value at the address of `i` is 3

Comment: is it a stretch to make the pointers point to unique values? like i guess each have their own unique int pointer?

Comment: @notacorn — why did you define `struct foo` to contain `int *bar` instead of `int bar`?  It would be far simpler to store the integer directly — and would use less space, too.

Comment: In the `fooPointer()`, we are assigning the same address (`i`) to all the `int` pointers (`bar`). So it prints the value at address of `i` every time

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it was more of a test of concept. Theoretically I might have a struct that needs to have a pointer to another struct which would be more applicable with the way I set up `Foo`.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I know thats **why** the code works the way it does, I'm just asking if it would be possible to rework the code such that the end result would be 0, 1, 2

Comment: @notacorn  Yes, it is possible. I modified the code . Please check it.